# How do I position text in TCPDF using the XY coordinates of the bottom left of the text?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'd like to position text so that if the font size changes, the baseline of the text will stay the same.

When I use

```
$pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
$pdf->Write(0, "Hello"......);
```

This sets the position of the text at its top left.

**Note:** I am using `write` to render the text.

Answer (score 6):

I used the following syntax and am able to chose the absolute position to start the table.

```
$pdf->SetFont('verdana', 'B', 18);
$pdf->SetXY(15, 20);

$output = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
.....
$pdf->writeHTML($output, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Example #57](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_057.phps) and [its showcase](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_057.pdf) you have the option to use

```
$pdf->Cell(30, 0, 'Bottom-Bottom', 1, $ln=0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'B', 'B');
```