# TCPDF placing a text content fixed near bottom of PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

Iam using TCPDF to create a PDF. But need to position a  text content fixed near bottom footer of the PDF page.
 Please see the attached image.
[image]
 How can i acheive this using TCPDF.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506228/how-do-i-position-text-in-tcpdf-using-the-xy-coordinates-of-the-bottom-left-of-t

Comment: @BilalAhmed . It is not putting content near footer as i have mentioned. Is there any other way.

Comment: I got answer from another stackoverflow thread. [Click here for answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187600/how-to-change-footer-of-a-particular-page-with-a-particular-header-title-in-tcpd/49214784)