# How to change footer of a particular page with a particular header title in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

Iam creating multiple pages in TCPDF using AddPage() method. When creating a second page , i call setHeaderData() method to set a header name. In some cases the first page might overflow and auto page break. I need to identify the page before the first page having the header title set  and change its footer only. How to achieve this using TCPDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to set a new property that will identify this page when the `Footer()` method is called by TCPDF.

The example below sets a new `PrintCoverPageFooter` property to `True` before creating the first page, then sets it to `False` before generating the second page. This property is then used in a conditional statement with the `page` property to create unique footers. There is also a `PrintCoverPageHeader` property that allows for custom headers on the cover page of the document.

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        if ($this->PrintCoverPageHeader) {
            $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< Cover Page Header >> ', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
        } else {
            $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< Other Page Header >> ', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
        }
    }

    public function Footer() {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        if ($this->PrintCoverPageFooter && $this->page == 1){
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Cover Page Footer '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        } elseif ($this->PrintCoverPageFooter && $this->page == 2){
                $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Cover Page Overflow Footer '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        } else {
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Other Page Footer'.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        }
    }
}

$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// Add first page with first page header and footer.
$pdf->PrintCoverPageHeader = True;
$pdf->PrintCoverPageFooter = True;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Write(0, str_repeat("Cover Page\n",80), '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// Add second page with other header and footer.
$pdf->PrintCoverPageHeader = False;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->PrintCoverPageFooter = False;
$pdf->Write(0, "Second Page", '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// Add third page with other header and footer.
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Write(0, "Third Page", '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: In this example the AddPage() is called manually. But in my case, the AddPage () is called during autopagebreak by TCPDF. Since we cannot know how many pages will be created by autopagebreak. How to handle this in that scenario. Any ideas ??.

Comment: @albert If the "first page" could result in multiple `AutoPageBreak` events, then you could use the following conditional to only print a footer to the last page of the "first page" in the example above:
`if ($this->PrintCoverPageFooter && !$this->PrintCoverPageHeader) {}`

Comment: @albert Multiple `AutoPageBreak` events can be tested by increasing the multiplier in `str_repeat()`.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain how it identifies the last page created by auto page break

Comment: The `AddPage()` method draws the footer on the previous page and the header on the new page. That is the reason why the new `PrintCoverPageFooter` property is set to false after the `AddPage()` method is called. The two properties will only be opposite during the second manual `AddPage()` event where you want the footer to go.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.